# ADODB Connection with Excel stored on Sharepoint (https)

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, connection, adodb

I am trying to use Excel VBA to import data from an Excel file that is stored on Sharepoint. I am using ADODB-Connection for this. When importing data from a locally saved Excel file, everything works as desired. However, the connection to Excel on Sharepoint fails.

**My previous procedure**

*Sharepoint URL:*

https://company.sharepoint.com/Shared Documents/General/topic1 & topic2/Landscape/Data_Dashboard/external_data.xlsx

*Converted URL:*
\\company.sharepoint.com\Shared%20Documents\General\topic1%20%26%20topic2\Landscape\Data_Dashboard\external_data.xlsx

```
Dim Connection as New ADODB.Connection
Dim constring as String
constring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\company.sharepoint.com\Shared%20Documents\General\topic1%20%26%20topic2\Landscape\Data_Dashboard\external_data.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;"
Connection.Open constring
```

**With this procedure I get the following error message:**

```
Runtime error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
The 'Open' method for the '_Connection' object failed
```

I have already found and tried to implement many posts on this topic, unfortunately without success.

Comment: Open the document from SP, save a local copy, and then query the local copy.